# Problem with mongoose for findOne JSON object in JSON object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an application with data.
They are stored in a mongo model.
But when I try to find by username like this:

`

```
 app. get('/profile/:name', function(req, res) {
        var name = req.params.name
        ModelAccount.findOne({
            user info: {
                username: name
            }
        })
```

`
mongo sends me null.
I think the problem is because my data is stored in 2 JSON objects but I'm not funding anything to fix this. So I need your help ^^
sorry it's my first post on this website so that explain my texts form
tysm

Comment: Would you show an example document?  You can paste it into a codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.get('/profile/:name',  async(req, res)=> {
        let name = req.params.name
        await ModelAccount.findOne({
            user_info.username: name
        })
```